# Determine whether $\sin x \left| {\sin x} \right|$ is differentiable and find the derivative function.

Tags: real-analysis

> Determine whether $f(x)=\sin x \left| {\sin x} \right|$ from
>   $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ is differentiable and find the derivative
>   function.

I know to let $g(x)=\sin x$. Then we have  $f(x)=g(x) \left| {g(x)} \right|$. Also $g'(x)=\cos x$.

What do I do from here?

Comment: Start by graphing the function $y=f(x)$. To prove $f$ is differentiable, you might want to first prove that if $g$ is differentiable everywhere, then $f(x)=g(x)\;|g(x)|$ is differentiable at $x_0$ if $g(x_0)\neq 0$.  If you can prove that, then check the cases where $g(x)=0$.  Amy Ngo's answer below is rather nice.  R. Burton's answer gives you a nice overview, but it leaves out some details and does not cover the "corner" cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply the chain rule, together with the product rule, at points where $\sin x\ne0$, because the derivative of $x\mapsto |x|$, for $x\ne0$, can be written $|x|/x$. Thus
$$
f'(x)=\cos x\lvert\sin x\rvert+\sin x\cos x\frac{\lvert\sin x\rvert}{\sin x}
=2\cos x\lvert\sin x\rvert
$$
Now observe that
$$
\lim_{x\to k\pi}f'(x)=0
$$
and therefore (by l'Hôpital), you have $f'(k\pi)=0$.

Thus the derivative is $f'(x)=2\cos x\lvert\sin x\rvert$, for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0):

The function $|\sin x|$ has corners at every $x = k \pi$, where $k$ is an integer. So while $f(x)$ is continuous everywhere on $\mathbb{R}$, it is not differentiable at any $x = k \pi$. However, it is still differentiable on intervals like $(k \pi, (k+1) \pi)$. Differentiating $f(x)$ on this interval gives us $f'(x) = \cos x |\sin x| + \sin x \frac{d}{dx} |\sin x|$. Over $(k \pi, (k + \frac{1}{2}) \pi)$, $\frac{d}{dx} |\sin x| = |\cos x|$, because $|\sin x|$ increases here. At $x = (k + \frac{1}{2}) \pi$, $|\sin x|$ attains its maximum of 1, so $\frac{d}{dx} |\sin x| = 0$. Over $((k + \frac{1}{2}) \pi, (k + 1) \pi)$, $\frac{d}{dx} |\sin x| = -|\cos x|$, because $|\sin x|$ decreases here. Hence, $f'(x)$ is piecewise-defined.

Comment: Actually this function is differentiable at all $x=k\pi$ as well and the derivative is $0$ at those points.

Answer (score 0):

Let $g(x)=\sin x$ and $h(x)=|x|$.

Then, $f(x)=(g \cdot h\circ g)(x)$.

By product rule $(g\cdot h\circ g)'=g'\cdot(h\circ g)+g\cdot(h\circ g)'$

By chain rule $(h\circ g)'=(h'\circ g)\cdot g'$

By [algebraic] substitution $f'=g'\cdot(h\circ g)+g\cdot((h'\circ g)\cdot g')$

This might look difficult at first, but each of the operations is quite simple, so it all works out nicely in the end.

Comment: you may wish to define the derivative of $h$ as $\text{sgn}(x)$ depending on the intended application - otherwise, the derivative is defined piecewise.